# Socket в сервисе уничтожается при закрытии программы Android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, service, клиент-сервер

У нас есть Андроид приложение и приложение Windows.

Windows приложение(java) - это сервер.

Андроид приложение(java) - это клиент, который общается с сервером в сервисе в потоке.

Соединение с сервером всегда держится, но как только приложение закрывается, то и соединение пропадает.
Как можно поднять соединение?

Comment: А куда и кем вы хотите подключаться если приложение не работает?

Comment: Чтобы сервис держал подключение, и ожидал сообщений.

Comment: Сервер должен и так держать открытым сокет(или что вы используете) и ожидать, что к нему подключаться. А держать соединение открытым с закрытым приложением невозможно.

Comment: Я хочу что бы сервер посылал сообщение на клиент. и что бы сервис его принимал. Как можно отправить сообщение если соединение потеряно? Сервис же не уничтожается при закрытии приложения.

Comment: Никак. Единственный вариант это не терять соединение(или восстанавливать его), как-то же работают всякие фейсбуки с посылкой "пуш"-сообщений. Как сделать конкретно это я вам не подскажу, тут нужен специалист именно по андройду.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте перед запуском потока(в котором вы соединяетесь с сервером),  установить его как демон: `setDaemon(true)`

```
MyThread thread=new MyThread();
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но мне больше не нужно в сервисе создавать поток с клиентом.